# What is wrong in the deploy of this Laravel application? Need I an effective domain instead the vhost used on my local environment?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am pretty new in PHP and moreover in Laravel and I am pretty desperate trying to deploy a **Laravel 5.4** application that works fine on my local environment on my Linux remote server.

So I think that it is something related to virtual **host configuration** or something like this (maybe also something related to the **.htaccess** file)

In my local environment (I am using **XAMPP** on Windows) I have setted this virtual host into the **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/HotelRegistration/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

So opening the **laravel.dev** URL I obtain the standard Laravel homepage (I have yet not replaced it with a landing page).

Then if I open this URL: http://laravel.dev/registration

I obtain the user registration page developed by me, this because I have this route into my **web.php** file into my project:

```
Route::resource('/registration', 'RegistrationController');
```

Then into my **RegistrationController.php** there is this method showing the **resources/views/registration/index.blade.php** view

```
public function index(){

    return view('/registration/index');

}
```

All works fine.

Now I have uploaded this Laravel website into my remote Linux server, into this folder: **/var/www/html/HotelRegistration**

But now my problem is that in this remote environment I have not virtual host (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion: from what I have understand the virtual host is used on the local environment to simulate a domain that Laravel need to point to the **public** folder, is it this reasoning correct?)

Anyway, this is the URL of the **public** folder of my deployed web site on my remote server:

http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/public/

As you can see opening it the Laravel landing page is correctly shown, the problem is that I can access to the previous **registration page**, the only way that I have found is to open this URL:

http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/public/index.php/registration

but it is pretty horrible and above all when the registration form is submitted it is generated a POST request toward this URL **http://89.36.211.48/registration** that end into a **404 Not Found** error.

So I think that it depend by the fact that in this remote server I can't use a **virtual host** that simulate a domain (as I have on my local environment), but I am not sure about it.

What can I do to solve the situation? Do you think that using a effective domain (something like: www.myregistration.com) that points to this directory of my remote server **http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/public/** I can solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly would you like to end up using? Would you like to be able to simply visit http://89.36.211.48/ and see your homepage? If so, you should be able to modify your Apache configuration to point the default document root at your `HotelRegistration/public` directory if you don't want to use a vhost. Really, it all depends on what you would ideally like to end up with.

Comment: Also, what is the OS of the deployment server? Is it CentOS or perhaps Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your domain in your server and need to reconfigure the apache. I'm considering you are having apache2 server so here you can do:

**Step 1** Go to the apache2 folder **cd /etc/apache2**

**Step 2** You can see sites-available folder go inside it **cd sites-available**

**Step 3** Make a new file name it **laravel.dev.conf**

**Step 4** Write down the following **sudo nano laravel.dev.conf**

**Step 5** Write down the following option:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@laravel.dev
     ServerName laravel.dev
     ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel.dev/public/
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/laravel.dev/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/laravel.dev/logs/access.log combined
     <Directory /var/www/html/laravel.dev/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 6** Now go to this folder/create a new one **cd /var/www/html/laravel.dev**

**Step 7** Copy/Install your laravel application here.

**Step 8** Now you can enable your site by typing **sudo a2ensite laravel.dev.conf**

**Step 9** Now restart the apache2 **sudo service apache2 restart**

Now you can have proper access to your domain. Hope this helps.

Comment: Only one doubt: so need I a proper domain (something like: myhotelregistration.com) pointing to this location? Or can I also access without a domain with a URL like "http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration" that not involve the use of a domain?

Comment: At this time I don't have a domain but I can only access to the "89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/public" path. Need I a domain or doing in this way it will work also accessing to my website using "89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration" as URL?

Comment: @AndreaNobili To my knowledge You need a domain for this, In any case you can access your laravel instance with `89.36.211.48/HotelRegstration/public` this will work, suppose you made a routes with name `signup` you can access by typing `89.36.211.48/HotelRegstration/public/signup`, there is no other way to access it directly like `89.36.211.48/HotelRegstration`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using XAMPP

Add the following into your `VirtualHost` Directive:

```
<Directory "LINUX PATH TO /HotelRegistration/public">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Your final `VirtualHost` Directive should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "LINUX PATH TO /HotelRegistration/public"
    ServerName 89.36.211.48

    <Directory "LINUX PATH TO /HotelRegistration/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After the configuration changes, restart Apache then you are good to go.

Comment: Where have I to add it in my remote Apache server on Linux? What file?

Comment: and why are you using the Windows path? I have the problem on my remote Linux server, not on my local Windows server

Comment: Locate the vhost file on your Linux Web Server then add the `AllowOverride All` Directive on it. The line that I have mentioned should be put on the file `httpd-vhosts`.

Comment: 2 doubts: 1) Why are you using my local windows path in your example, I have the problem on remote Linux server, not on my local windows XAMPP.
2) Doing in this way I am declaring a laravel.dev virtual host on my remote server but how can I call it from the outside?

Comment: I just used the path as an example, so, sorry for the misunderstanding it may have caused. The same setting should work as long as you are using Apache as your Web Server. As for the second doubt, you need to have a DNS registration for your domain.

Comment: Ok...another doubt: where can I obtain this DNS registration? and what have I to do when I obtained it? Have I to combine the laravel.dev defined virtual host with the IP of my server on this DNS registration or what? Can you explain me it in details because I am very new in this stuff

Comment: You can always use the IP Address of your server to save yourself from the trouble of registering your domain name. DNS Registrations require payment. You can just tweak the VirtualHost Directives in your Apache configuration so that it will serve your Laravel Application even when accessed using the IP Address of your remote Linux web server.

Comment: ok but in my virtual host configuration file have I to add the first code snipped or the second one posted by you?

Comment: Use the second one. Don't forget to change the Directory & DocumentRoot to match the filesystem on your Linux Web Server. Use the path of your Laravel Application on your Linux Server. Cheers! :)