# Why I can't correctly deploy this Laravel web site on my remote Linux server? Is it a virtual host configuration issue?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am very new in **PHP** and moreover in **Laravel** (I came from Java) and I am going totaly crazy trying to correctly deploy a Laravel 5.4 projects that works fine in my XAMPP local environment on my Linux server. The problem should be related to **virtual host configuration** but I can't find a solution also asking question and reading documentation.

In my local environment (I am using XAMPP on Windows) I have setted this virtual host into the C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/HotelRegistration/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

So opening the **laravel.dev** URL I obtain the standard Laravel homepage (I have yet not replaced it with a landing page).

Then if I open this URL: http://laravel.dev/registration

I obtain the user registration page developed by me, this because I have this route into my **web.php** file into my project:

```
Route::resource('/registration', 'RegistrationController');
```

Then into my RegistrationController.php there is this method showing the **resources/views/registration/index.blade.php** view

```
public function index(){
    return view('/registration/index');
}
```

In local environment, with the **laravel.dev** vhost pointing to the **document root** of my Laravel website, it works fine.

Now I have uploaded this Laravel website into my remote Linux server, into this folder: /var/www/html/HotelRegistration

But now my problem is that in this remote environment I had not virtual host (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion: from what I have understand the virtual host is used on the local environment to simulate a domain that Laravel need to point to the public folder, is it this reasoning correct?)

Anyway, this is the URL of the **public** folder of my deployed web site on my remote server:

http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/public/

As you can see opening it the Laravel landing page is correctly shown, the problem is that I can access to the previous registration page, the only way that I have found is to open this URL:

http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/public/index.php/registration

but it is pretty horrible and above all when the registration form is submitted it is generated a POST request toward this URL http://89.36.211.48/registration that end into a **404 Not Found error**.

In the past I explained the situation here: [What is wrong in the deploy of this Laravel application? Need I an effective domain instead the vhost used on my local environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556771/what-is-wrong-in-the-deploy-of-this-laravel-application-need-i-an-effective-dom)

but now I have do some changes to my Apache configuration followint the suggestion given in the previous post (adapting the answer to my folder structure).

So into this Apache folder **/etc/apache2/sites-available** I created and enabled the **laravel.dev.conf** related to my new **vhost**, having this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin mymain@gmail.com
     ServerName 89.36.211.48
     ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/HotelRegistration/public/
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/HotelRegistration/storage/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/HotelRegistration/storage/logs/access.log combined
     <Directory /var/www/html/HotelRegistration/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The path are related to where this website is installed on my remote server I am absolutly not sure if these configuration are ok, expecially about the **ServerName** value (I put here the IP of my server, is it correct?)

Then I enabled this virtual host using this statment:

```
sudo a2ensite laravel.dev.conf
```

and I restart apache.

Ok, the problem now is: what have I to do to correctly access to this website?

I still have the same problem, that is:

- I still access to the Laravel landing page by this URL: http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/public/
- I still access to the registration form page by the horrible URL: http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/public/index.php/registration
- Submitting the form I still go to http://89.36.211.48/registration and obtain the same **404 Not Found error** page.

So my doubts are:

1. Is it the virtual host correctly configured?
2. If it is correct what have I to do to correctly access to this web site? Need I a domain (if yes: what have to point this domain?) or can I use a path into my server in some way (something like: http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/)

Comment: I also work with virtual host locally but on remote server I don't because it is usually more complicated then my current solution. And that is copying full project in separate folder (e.g. 'system') in your app folder (in your case 'HotelRegistration') and then in app folder (above 'system') copy all from  'public' folder and in index.php change paths that you have there e.g. from `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';` to `require __DIR__.'/system/bootstrap/autoload.php';` that way you'll have start page at http://89.36.211.48/HotelRegistration/

Comment: @jakob Please, can you explain me better your solution (steo by step)

Comment: Does your remote server have a `.htaccess` file in the web root?

Comment: Check if the apache mod rewrite is enabled on your server

Answer (score 0):

I am expanding my comment here.

Set folder structure like on image:

[image: Laravel folder structure]

In `index.php` change paths like this:

line 22

```
require __DIR__.'/system/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

line 36

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/system/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Thats all what I do when transferring Laravel app to server (and changing .env for database). Sometimes I have to change permissions for storage folders but thats it.